# .htaccess Query String Redirects for folders and individually

Tags: regex, .htaccess, query-string, redirect

Hello fellow awesomers..

I have 81 redirects to add in to .htaccess that have query strings, but I can't figure out how to do this. I worked out how to do it for one page, but how do you do it for folders and query strings that have similarities? I have added in DPI to remove the question mark in the new URL.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^test_id=1$
RewriteRule http://domain.com/test.html? [R=301,DPI,L]
```

But I have maaaaany! 
Most of the query strings are;

```
folder/name.php?=1 
folder/name.php?=2
```

OR

```
folder2/name1.php?=1
folder2/name2.php?=2
```

Is there a way to combine the query strings so instead of doing it manually for all 81 query strings to target it per `folder/name.php`? Some of the query strings are going to the same redirect url, others are individual.

Thank you for any help! 
Peace out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this single rule to handle all redirects:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .+
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /$1?[R=301,NE,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help:

```
RewriteRule ^/*(([aA-zZ-]+[0-9-]*)/*([aA-zZ-]+[0-9-]*.php)$ *<REPLACE_WITH_PAGE_TO_REDIRECT>*?$1=$2 [L]
```